# Combining multiple actions in onClick

Tags: javascript

I have built a "snippets" HTML document in which I have dozens various snippets with their codes in a "readonly" textarea. So the snippets may be easily copied inthe clipboard and pasted into a webpage content.
I don't know, how to pack the whole "onClick" content into one function. This would save a lot of code in the whole "snippets" document, instead of using this onClick="" in each included snippet.
This is my code:

```html
<h2><em>Snippet:</em> Intro page - bold text</h2>
<form>
  <input title="One click transfers the code to the clipboard" type="button" value="Hilight & copy the code" onClick="this.form.code.select(),this.value = 'Hilighted code copied', document.execCommand('copy')">
  <textarea name="code" readonly="readonly">
    <!-- SNIPPET START -->
    *snippet code here*
    <!-- SNIPPET END -->
    </textarea>
</form>
```

[image: Snippet block example on a HTML Snippets page]

Comment: use `;` instead of `,` in the `onClick` method : `onClick="this.form.code.select(); this.value = 'Hilighted code copied';  document.execCommand('copy')"`

Comment: This way it works. Regardless if "," or ";" is used. But I need the whole "onClick" code insert into each "snippet" form.
I would prefer the "onClick" content put into one function and in all onClicks call only this function, instead of using the whole "onClick" line.
I mean something like:
function SelectCopy{this.form.select();this.value='new value';document.execCommand('copy')}
and then to use only
onClick = "SelectCopy()" in each snippet form.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should use `;` instead of `,` but if you have more than one snippet, you should delegate

```js
document.getElementById("container").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  let tgt = e.target.closest("input");
  if (tgt && tgt.matches(".copy")) {
    const textarea = tgt.nextElementSibling;
    textarea.select();
    tgt.value = 'Hilighted code copied';
    document.execCommand('copy')
  }
  else tgt = e.target.closest("textarea");
  if (tgt.matches("[name=code]")) tgt.select()

})
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <h2><em>Snippet:</em> Intro page - bold text</h2>
  <input class="copy" title="One click transfers the code to the clipboard" type="button" value="Hilight & copy the code" />
  <textarea name="code" readonly="readonly">
<!-- SNIPPET START -->
*snippet code 1 here*
<!-- SNIPPET END -->
</textarea>
  <h2><em>Snippet:</em> Intro page - bold text</h2>
  <input class="copy" title="One click transfers the code to the clipboard" type="button" value="Hilight & copy the code" />
  <textarea name="code" readonly="readonly">
<!-- SNIPPET START -->
*snippet code 2 here*
<!-- SNIPPET END -->
</textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: Super!!! Thaks a lot.

Comment: One more thing. The same code "<input...>" is used in one document repeatidly a couple of times. I can't find the way how to replace the code with a PHP variable. I mean to define the code-string on the beginning of the document and on respective places to use only the variable.
This is the code:
    <input class="copyBtn" title="Click to hilight & copy" type="button" value="Hilight & copy the code" />

Comment: I am sorry I do not understand your requirement

Answer (score 0):

Solved.
The document must be *.PHP.
The variable shall be declared, e.g.:

```
<?php 
$BTN = '<input class="copyBtn" title="Click to hilight & copy" type="button" value="Hilight & copy the code" />';
?>
```

The usage then is:

```
<?php echo $BTN;?>
```